# How to calculate number of business days (Monday to friday) between two dates in hive?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, hive, hiveql

The no of business days between 2 dates in hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple question but complex answer :) Please note, i have chosen sat and sun as non business day.
First of all you need to generate a time series. Then count no of weekdays in the series.
Step 1 - Creating time series can be created using `lateral view posexplode.`

```
lateral view posexplode(split(space(datediff(t.end_dt,t.start_dt)),' ')) pe as i,x
```

Step 2 - Calculate count if day is neither sat nor sun using `extract(days of week timestamp_col)` function.

Sunday - 1
Saturday - 7

```
case when extract(dayofweek from day) in (1,7) then 0 else 1 end
```

So, complete code will look like below -

```
select end_date, start_date, 
sum(case when extract(dayofweek from day) in (1,7) or or to_date(start_date )=to_date(end_date) then 0 else 1 end) no_of_week_day
from (
select  end_date, start_date , date_add (t.start_date,pe.i)   as Day
from    etl.x t
        lateral view posexplode(split(space(datediff(t.end_date,t.start_date)),' ')) pe as i,x )  rs
group by end_date, start_date
```

I ran above SQL for sample data.
[image: SQL Result]
EDIT : I updated the SQL with OR clause.

Comment: Hey hi , I did try this code but instead of getting 0 when there is no difference in the dates i am getting no of week days.

Comment: This situation can be easily handled using `OR`. Could you pls refer to updated SQL in answer?

Answer (score 0):

select flw_up_actv_dt,flw_up_dt,
sum (case when extract (dayofweek from day) in (1,7) then 0 else 1 end) no_of_week_day
from (
select flw_up_actv_dt , flw_up_dt , date_add(t.flw_up_dt,pe.i) as day
from consumer_usrs.commitments_mgexp t
lateral view posexplode(split(space(datediff(t.flw_up_actv_dt , t.flw_up_dt)),' ')) pe as i,x ) rs
group by flw_up_actv_dt ,flw_up_dt;

OUTPUT:
2020-01-02  2020-01-02  146
2020-01-03  2020-01-02  398
2020-01-03  2020-01-03  176
2020-01-04  2020-01-02  4
2020-01-04  2020-01-03  9
2020-01-04  2020-01-04  0